# Only Take Last Item After X Seconds

Tags: reactive-programming, rxjs

I am trying to skip items from a stream until n-seconds, and then take the last item that was passed in the stream. This is what I have so far:

```js
const delayedState$ = state$.delay(1000);
state$.buffer(
  delayedState$
).filter(
  (buffer) => buffer && buffer.length > 0
).publishReplay(1).refCount().map(
  (buffer) => buffer.slice(-1).pop()
).subscribe((state) => {
  saveState({
    buttonCount: state.buttonCount
  });
})
```

But this seems messy, and doesn't seem to work when the stream has many changes in very short succession. I am basically trying to follow this:
https://github.com/tayiorbeii/egghead.io_idiomatic_redux_course_notes/blob/master/03-Persisting_the_State_to_the_Local_Storage.md

My constraint; it **has** to be the last item after n-seconds, *not* the first item and then wait n-seconds.

Answer (score 1):

In this demo the `source` Observable emits 10 values with 1s delay between them.

All values are ignored until the inner Observable delayed by 5s emits a value and then only the last values is passed to the subscriber (the last value is `9` because `interval()` counts value from `0`):

```
let source = Observable.interval(1000).take(10);

source.skipUntil(Observable.of(true).delay(5000))
    .takeLast(1)
    .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

See live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/zklJWnnKzHu3smNmr0T2?p=preview